# Internal API cannot be accessed through Internal APIGEE

Tags: api, proxy, apigee

Have a standard search API deployed in internal organisation Server,possibly a different region in AWS. Tried to create a proxy for this API through APIGEE(deployed in internal network). When it is accessed through apigee proxy I receive 503 service unavailable.

[image: Trace result from Apigee]

Note: Even in postman cannot access this service directly. It can be accessed only when a proxy is set up in postman settings.

So What should be done to access this through apigee proxy url. I believe some configuration changes is required.

Comment: Have you ever try to see the details of this problem in system.log yet?

Comment: @Pim H where should I check this system.log. Can you please provide more details on this.

Comment: It is usually in path /opt/apigee/var/log/edge-message-processor/logs/system.log. It will be show entire detail of transaction. You can try to find by proxy name.